# auto increment field in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, auto-increment

I'm creating an empty table using the Google BigQuery WebUI, and I'd like to have a field that auto-increments every time I add a record to the table. In MYSQL it would look something like this

```
CREATE TABLE smoker_info (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
meat_type string,
kilos varchar(255), 
PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
```

Is there a way to create the `ID` field in BigQuery?

My plan is to use the `smoker_info` table to hold general information about the meat I'm smoking, and I would have another table that holds temperature readings.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

BigQuery doesn't have

- `auto increment`
- `index`
- `primary key`

features.

It's not a replacement of the relational databases, instead it complements them and works great with large data sets (several terabytes). If you want to store relational data on GCP check out [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/).

Comment: I was using Google Cloud SQL, but I was drawn to BigQuery's serverlessnes. I have a relatively small amount of data to host, and I was getting hit by a few dollars a month from the MySQL db overhead charges (especially when I forgot to turn it off after I was done using it). I guess BigQuery isn't the right tool for what I'm trying to do. Thank you